# Associate a model with 2 hasone relations node.js

Tags: node.js

i have 3 models 1) questions 2) Answers 3) comments
- each answer has a question 
- each comment either has a question or an answer and not both.

How can i define the above associations in my model?

Comment: I think you have to add a field named `associationId` and another field named `associationType`. in `associationType` , store type of association (e.g `ENUM("Question","Answer")` )

Comment: i will try out this option. I forgot to mention that i am facing an issue if i just declare 2 has one relations on comment. i think that will not help.

Comment: are you using any ORMs ?

Comment: yes i am using node-orm. The exact issue is if i try to retrieve comments to an answer i get it but i wont get comments to a question. same is true vice versa. Any suggestions on how to go about

Answer (score 0):

change your comment model to something like this :

```
...
associationId : { type: 'integer' }
associationType : ["Question", "Answer"]
...
```

and when you want to use this relation, first select `comment` and check for its `associationType`, if it's `Question` then select from `question` with `associationId` and if it's `Answer` select from `Answer` with that `associationId`

if you want to use `hasOne` , you have to declare your model to have a field named `questionId` and another field named `answerId` and put their default value to `0` and when you want to use it, check for non-zero field and get data from desired table.

Comment: You mean to say no need to declare hasone relations? I get what you say but will that call for changes to my model structure. I already have has one relations defined